# What does the use of a list name with an if clause mean in Python?

Tags: python

In Python What does it mean if the name of the list is used follwoed by an if clause
e.g. in the code that I am looking at
`if listname: listname.pop()`

here what does **if listname** do?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 0):

This is simply checking is list is not empty (`listname` should refer only to the name) and then if it is not empty, it pop's the last element from it.